# Opening new image with PIL (python) syntax issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL to convert thousands of images from .png to .jpg so that I can use openCV to load the images and manipulate them.

The problem is that I have a file which contains locations to the images like:

```
project/data/image/000000000.png
project/data/image/000000001.png
```

The problem is, when I read the these lines inside the variable:

```
file = open("project/data/loc.txt", "r")
var = [ line[:-1] for line in file ]
```

My variable var, contains the same lines as the loc.txt:

```
project/data/image/000000000.png
project/data/image/000000001.png
```

But, then comes the PIL. From what I've been able to find, and worked, to load the image I need to specify the argument as:

```
Image.open(r"location")
```

As I have var which contains series of strings, using:

```
image = []
for v in var:
    image.append( Image.open(???????????????) )
```

I do not know what to do.

I cannot concat "r" + v, as that would like to 'r"location"' (string inside a string).

What should I do? Do you have any suggestions? I cannot avoid reading the file containing locations, as it is impossible for me to manually type down each location for series of more than few thousand times.

Comment: Try `im = Image.open(var[0])` or, if in your loop `Image.open(v)`

Comment: I've tried doing that, it does not work. It throws error: fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb"), but when I try to say open("location", "r") it crashes as well with the same error. When I type it like in question: open(r"location"), it passes.

Comment: Try printing `v` in your loop.

Comment: The same result. :(

Comment: How can you get the same result? Surely it prints the filenames? Does it print them correctly? Do your filenames actually have non-ASCII characters in them?

Comment: The locations that your provided in the question, only contained forward slashes `/`, so if the locations are for real, then problem won't arise as forward slashes are interpreted as it is, without raising any Unicode Escape/Decode Error (happens in case of backslashes). Secondly, `line[:-1]` would truncate the last character of the last line, if the last line doesn't contain a `\n` in the end.

Comment: I've tried Image.open(var[0]) and Image.open(var), sorry, Mark. My bad. Vasu, I understand that. It has the end "\n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the location, as a raw string you can try using `fr""` for that purpose.

```
location = "project/data/image/000000000.png"

img = Image.open(fr"{location}")
```

We are using [f string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), with r (raw). This allows us to use a raw ('r') on string values at runtime.

**NOTE:-**
This only works for python versions above 3.5 (or python version >= 3.6).